# React: useState not preserving updated state upon click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Update: I was truly trying to reinvent the wheel here, the code below works if you use it in conjunction with React's Link or NavLink instead of anchor tags, it has built-in listening functionality that will keep track of the page you are currently on and pass along the updated state accordingly as your route changes to a different page.Thank you to everyone that chimed in and pointed me in the right direction!

I'm still fresh off the block with React, especially with hooks, but what I'm trying to accomplish is to trigger the 'active' tab class of my navbar elements through conditional rendering and managing state with useState.
However, when I call 'setActiveTabIdx' upon click, I can't tell if it's not updating state at all, or if it is and is resetting to the default value upon re-render. I was trying to use my dev tools to monitor upon click but it's happening too fast for me to say one way or the other. I've messed around a fair bit at this point trying a number of different things if anyone would be willing to take a look, thanks!

```
const NavBar = () => {

  const [activeTabIdx, setActiveTabIdx] = useState(0)

  const navItems = ['About', 'Services', 'Oils', 'New Patients', 'Courses', 'Recommendations', 'Contact' ]

  const renderedItems = navItems.map((nav, idx) => {

    const active = idx === activeTabIdx ? 'active' : ''

    return (
    <a 
      onClick={() => setActiveTabIdx(idx)} 
      href={`${nav.split(' ').join('').toLowerCase()}`} 
      className={`${active} item`}
      key={idx}
      >{nav}</a>
    )
  })

  return (
    <div className="ui tabular menu">
      {renderedItems}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: It appears that you're using onClick in combination with href; the router will handle the href change after the onClick, and effectively reset your state after re-rendering the component with your updated route state. You should be setting the initial state to the correct value for the current page, and `useRouter` for your page transitions, rather than an href, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change state (which is done) and then redirect user to other page (which is also done). The state resets after redirection.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is resetting, I added this block to check:

```
const NavBar = () => {

  const [activeTabIdx, setActiveTabIdx] = useState(0)

  const navItems = ['About', 'Services', 'Oils', 'New Patients', 'Courses', 'Recommendations', 'Contact' ]
  
  // --------- Start block --------- 

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log(`current state: ${activeTabIdx}`);
  }, [activeTabIdx]);

  // --------- End block --------- 

  const renderedItems = navItems.map((nav, idx) => {

    const active = idx === activeTabIdx ? 'active' : ''

    return (
    <a 
      onClick={() => setActiveTabIdx(idx)} 
      href={`${nav.split(' ').join('').toLowerCase()}`} 
      className={`${active} item`}
      key={idx}
      >{nav}</a>
    )
  })

  return (
    <div className="ui tabular menu">
      {renderedItems}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

And to check [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-flower-hlniq?file=/src/App.js:317-407)